# Setup a http proxy server in linux so that Web users behind a big firewall in another country can access the Web without filtering

Tags: proxy, http, squid

I've already setup a SSH server. I can create a socks proxy and proxify the Internet connections from within a country that censores the Internet. The problem is that SSH proxies are too slow and for that, I'd like to have a http proxy server. I didn't manage to configure a squid since I guess it's for LAN networks.

Do you know any http proxy server that would "route web traffic"?

Best Regards

Comment: You should describe the problems with squid and its configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to run a proxy so a (large) group of users can access the web "unfiltered".

Squid is probably the "standard" tool (outside of the MS world) to act as a proxy; you haven't described what problems you had with that.

Having said that, running what is essentially an open-proxy exposes you and your machine to various avenues of threats, from basic security (someone rooting your box) to legal implications (someone using your proxy to access child porn and you get held accountable). I am hesitant to encourage you to do so without making sure you fully understand the risks. Personally, as someone who has to deal with abused proxies regularly, the last thing I want to see on the internet is another "misconfigured" open-proxy.

Comment: The proxy is for my family living in Iran and of course I don't want people to use it for child porn neither other illegal Websites. I've no idea how should I configure squid so that specific users (living in Iran) can access to my server and use it as a proxy to bypass filtering in Iran. Would you please tell how exactly this is called so that I can google it?

Comment: There are a couple of options; the best would be to setup a VPN (using OpenVPN for example) so they need to connect to your server using that, and configure Squid to only allow access via the VPN. Alternatively, you can configure Squid to require username/password authentication, this option is less secure though. Both options are outside the scope of this site, but if you do have any specific problems, do open a new question.

Comment: The problem is that VPN don't work anymore. PPTP was working before. openvpn has been blocked for longtime. Therefore proxies socks and http are best solution. I already use socks proxy over ssh, however it's too slow and I'd prefer to provide http proxy as well

Comment: Interesting; you've piqued my interest in finding out how they block OpenVPN. It's not as simple as changing the port number and/or swap UDP/TCP? Perhaps you can use stunnel as detailed in this write-up (too long to post here, sorry) http://www.jeffyestrumskas.com/index.php/how-to-setup-a-secure-web-proxy-using-ssl-encryption-squid-caching-proxy-and-pam-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're using as an HTTP server in this case, but what you're requesting can be pretty easily done through Apache's mod_proxy and some forward proxy-ing configuration. You can see some details at:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

The long and short would be to configure your forward proxy to a port of your choosing, then configure your browser to request from this proxy. Be sure to implement some form of locking down your proxy from the outside world, as this can (as well as violate a number of terms of services) pose a serious security risk.

A more detailed guide on configuring the forward proxy can be found here (under Forward and Controlling your Proxy):

http://apache.active-venture.com/mod/mod_proxy2.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll give a try and will tell you if I managed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use kerio control as a vpn server and then u can change the port for vpn and create many users , it works fast and good enough even for Iran ;)